# MySQL - select query empty case values - multiple categories

Tags: mysql

I am running a query on a MySQL database to extract weighted counts by categories. There are two categories - location and group. Here is the code I am using -

```
select t.grpnm, a.rcgrp1, ifnull(t.pwgt0,0) as pwgt0
from (
select grpnm,
CASE 
    WHEN rcgrp = 1 THEN 'r1' 
    when rcgrp = 2 then 'r2' 
    when rcgrp = 3 then 'r3' 
    when rcgrp = 4 then 'r4' 
    when rcgrp = 5 then 'r5' 
    ELSE 'r6' END AS rcgrp1,
sum(wgt) as pwgt0
FROM data1
GROUP BY grpnm,rcgrp1 with rollup
)t
right join (
    select 'r1' as rcgrp1 union
    select 'r2' union
    select 'r3' union
    select 'r4' union
    select 'r5' union
    select 'r6' 
)a on t.rcgrp1 = a.rcgrp1 
union
select grpnm,'total' as rcgrp1,
sum(wgt) as pwgt0
from data1
group by grpnm,rcgrp1 order by grpnm,rcgrp1
```

You can see an example on SQL fiddle here - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/24842/13
The resulting table is missing one of the rcgrp categories for Napa (r4) because the full data set did not have any records for the 'r4' rcgrp category. Unfortunately, I have no way of knowing if a particular data set will be missing records for the rcgrp category and so my code needs to as flexible as possible.

The query is part of a web query application and I need to ensure both the record count and record order so that my php loop can extract and present the correct data in the correct order.

I need help with two things: 1)adding a row that corresponds to 'r4' for Napa county with a 0 value to maintain the record count while preserving the order; and 2) having totals by grpnm as I need to be able to calculate percentages in my php code.

I've done a search and can only find solutions for single-category queries (examples: [MySQL CASE WHEN THEN empty case values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960020/mysql-case-when-then-empty-case-values) and [Selecting rollup after join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24675168/selecting-rollup-after-join)). If there is a solution out there that anyone knows of feel free to post it.

Thanks!

Comment: How do we know 4 is *missing*? Maybe 7 is missing too. And what's your PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: The r1-r6 categories are based responses tabulated in a survey dataset. There is no r7 category. There's no primary key for the database as there are no tabulation categories that are unique to each record. Check the sqlfiddle link to see a micro version of the query and dataset.